# Postfix - Forward mail externally through relay

Tags: email, postfix, relay

I manage the mail server for *mydomain.com*. Some users have a local IMAP mailbox, but for some their address is an alias and I'd like to forward their message to their external address. I've configured these in MySQL and it's working great:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

So mail from *sender@somewhere.tld* to *alias_user@mydomain.com* should be delivered to *external_user@other.tld*. I have this working using SRS, which rewrites the envelope FROM; otherwise the recipient may reject the message because my server is not a valid origin for *somethere.tld*. So far, so good.

```
sender_canonical_maps = tcp:postsrsd:10001
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:postsrsd:10002
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient
```

Now, to deliver these external mails, I'd like to use an SMTP server. I was experimenting with Mailjet's free tier. I've added *mydomain.com* as a valid sender and it works fine for mail originating from my mail server. But for forwarded messages, Mailjet is looking at the header FROM, not the envelope FROM. And then it says "hey, you need to validate that *sender@somewhere.tld* is a valid sender" and queues the mail.

What is the cleanest way to get this working? Options that I considered

- Find the magic switch in Mailjet that looks at the sending server or envelope from to decide if the sender is authorized / validated.
- Use another SMTP service that looks at the envelope instead of the header from. I'm not sure if that exists, and I like Mailjet (also for other purposes).
- Let Postfix rewrite the header from. But how do I do that, and how do I make sure that if the recipient at *other.tld* presses Reply, the reply goes back to the original sender -- do I add a *Reply-To*?
- Let Postfix send the mail from *no-reply@mydomain.com* 'on behalf of' *sender.somewhere.tld*. I'm not sure which combination of header rewriting would get this working.
- ... -- open to other suggestions!